# Draw Bash script output with Kibana

Tags: indexing, plot, charts, kibana, filebeat

I am doing a basic url chek by using CURL. I have my **Kibana**, **Elasticsearch** and **filebeat** installed. I am able to see
logs in **Kibana**. So kibana can read /var/log/**kibana.customized.jt.log**

[Here is my Kibana screen [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64PX0.png)

However when I want to visualize my data there are no such columns.
In future I will use logstash so I will need to write som grok {} filter.

**For now** I assume I need to write som kind of **"index"** or so...
to be able ploting **simpe X,Y chart** with **http respones** on **Y** axis and timestamp
on **X** asis

If needed I will change my log format - it is not a problem.

Could anyone help with that.

```
for i in {1..50} ; do awk 'BEGIN {"date +'%Y.%m.%d-%T'"|getline d;"curl -sI ip.ip.ip.ip/" | getline; printf "{\"timestampx\": \"%s\", \"statusx\": \"%s\"}\n", d, $2}' >> /var/log/kibana.customized.jt.log; sleep 1; done

cat /var/log/kibana.customized.jt.log
...
{"timestampx": "2016.12.13-11:47:51", "statusx": "200"}
{"timestampx": "2016.12.13-11:47:52", "statusx": "200"}
{"timestampx": "2016.12.13-11:47:53", "statusx": "200"}
{"timestampx": "2016.12.13-11:47:54", "statusx": "200"}
{"timestampx": "2016.12.13-11:47:55", "statusx": "200"}
{"timestampx": "2016.12.13-11:47:56", "statusx": "200"}
{"timestampx": "2016.12.13-11:47:57", "statusx": "200"}
{"timestampx": "2016.12.13-11:47:58", "statusx": "200"}
{"timestampx": "2016.12.13-11:47:59", "statusx": "200"}
{"timestampx": "2016.12.13-11:48:00", "statusx": "200"}
...
```

Comment: What version are you using for these components? Can you mention?

Comment: Well currently i am using up to date versions, it means 5.x.x.

Comment: You can use Ingest Node with grok processor which will eliminate your usage of Logstash.
Reference:-
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/grok-processor.html